# Using pretrained models for mnist dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mnist

The problem when I want to use pre-trained VGG16 is that is expects shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), but found shape=(32, 28, 28).
What can I do in order to use the model? or should I not use convnets for images under 244 x 244 pixels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resize using tensorflow as follows:

```
(x_train, y_train), (_, _) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

print(x_trian.shape) # (60000, 28, 28)

# train set / data 
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=-1)
x_train = tf.image.resize(x_train, [224,224]) 

print(x_train.shape) # (60000, 224, 224, 1)
```

Comment: It helped, but now it says it expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 3 but received input with shape (32, 244, 244, 1)

Comment: use colorized-MNIST dataset to have a depth of 3